# Oblique stripes resulting from bilinear interpolation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation, octave

I'm trying to write a function in GNU Octave that does bilinear interpolation on a PGM image. The result isn't that great: I keep getting oblique stripes of different shades all over the image. Also, the rows and columns that are added during interpolation are darker than they should. Could someone help me by pointing out the problem, please?

```
function bilinear(img)
    data = imread(img);

    for n = 1 : 2 : (rows(data) - 1)  * 2
        average = average_vector(data(n, 1:end), data(n+1:1:end));
        data = [data(1:n, 1:end); average; data(n+1:rows(data), 1:end)];
    end

    for n = 1 : 2 : (columns(data) - 1) * 2
        average = average_vector(data(1:rows(data), n), data(1:rows(data), n+1));
        data = [data(1:rows(data), 1:n) average data(1:rows(data), n+1:end)];
    end

    imwrite(data, strcat("out_bilinear_", img));
end

function res = average_vector(a, b)
    res = zeros(size(a));
    for n = 1 : length(a)
        res(n) = (a(n) + b(n)) / 2;
    end
end
```

Here's an image showing the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating through the input image row-by-row (or column-by-column), but inserting new rows (or columns) as you go.  I'm pretty sure this will screw your indexing up.

I would suggest creating a new output matrix, rather than modifying the original.  This will be considerably faster, too.

Incidentally, your `average_vector` function can be written simply as `res = (a + b) / 2;`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I can do `(a + b) / 2` and not need `average_vector`. The problem was a colon instead of a comma: this `data(n+1:1:end)` instead of this `data(n+1, 1:end)`. It works now. I know this is not very efficient, but at this point it doesn't matter that much.